# pyvnc2swf not working? outputs video of duration 0sec

Tags: python, linux, video-conversion, video-codecs

i need to convert video from swf to flv. im using pyvnc2swf : edit.py but it's not working. shows no errors but outputs a file with one blank frame.

**here is the command:**

```
/usr/share/pyvnc2swf/edit.py -o outlet.flv -s 1 1.swf
```

**output:**

```
Using pygame 1.9.1release there is no soundcard Input movie: version=7, size=718x351, framerate=24fps, frames=1, duration=0.0s. Output movie size: 718x351 Scanning source swf file: 1.swf... .1 frames written (duration=0.0s)
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer on my own :
pyvnc2swf is working perfectly but it won't work with the swf's which are interative(require clicking etc). u can only convert simple swf's to flv.

Comment: you can make your own answer as the answer to your question

Comment: How to use edit.py to convert swf to video in windows.